# Display website on google search when deployed with vercel

Tags: next.js, metadata, title, favicon, google-search

I used google search console and my website showed up on google search like this.
[Image on google search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcf2x.png)
This is my code in nextjs. I already have favicon and icon file but it's not displayed on google search. I also add title tag is "A New LifeStyle" but the name that displayed on google search is vercel.
[Code nextJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0vKc.png)
How do I resolve this problem. Thank you very much!

I try to change the title and the favicon file but it's not applied on google search.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text and not as an image. Also, I'm not sure what the google verification string is, but if it is some api key, I would suggest you to regenerate another key.  Please do not include any credentials in your posts in the future.